# Send A Message Across The Internet Using UDP And C++

Tags: c++, networking, udp, winsock

I created a simple client/server program in which the client is able to send messages to the server.

This works on my local computer, and even works when running it on different computers on the same network when I modify the `IP_ADDRESS` in my client program to be that for the server's IP address.

However, this does not work when testing it with devices that are not a part of the same network, even if I change it to be my public IP address. I am pretty sure it would have to somehow use both my public IP address as well as my server's IP address in order to work as I intend, if I am understanding things properly. However, I am unsure of how I would go about implementing that.

Ultimately, all I want to know is, how can I send a single message from one known device to another known device across the Internet using UDP with C++? I don't really care about the specific implementation beyond that, so that I can use it for a video game I am trying to make.

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &wsadata);

    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot Start Winsock\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET in = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in serverHint;
    serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY;
    serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverHint.sin_port = htons(54000);

    if (bind(in, (sockaddr*) &serverHint, sizeof(serverHint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't Bind Socket " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientLength = sizeof(client);
    ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength);

    char buffer[1024];
    
    while (true)
    {
        ZeroMemory(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        int numOfBytes = recvfrom(in, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)  &client, &clientLength);

        if (numOfBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Error Recieving Client Message " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        char clientIP[256];
        ZeroMemory(clientIP, sizeof(clientIP));

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIP, sizeof(clientIP));

        std::cout << "Message Received From [" << clientIP << "] = " << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket(in);

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

const char* IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &wsadata);

    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot Start Winsock\n";
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(54000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_ADDRESS, &server.sin_addr);

    SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    std::string message = "Hello!\n";

    for (size_t index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
        int sendOk = sendto(out, message.c_str(), message.size() + 1, 0, (sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));

        if (sendOk == SOCKET_ERROR)
            std::cout << "Failed To Send" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket(out);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried running my client on the same computer as my server, which worked, and also tried running my client on different devices in the same network, which worked when I updated my `IP_ADDRESS`. However, it did not work when my client was a part of an outside network, despite being connected to the internet and the `IP_ADDRESS` being modified to be the public IP address of the server.

Comment: Where did you run the server program?

Comment: You'll have to do some network diagnostics on your own, to determine exactly what goes over the network. This looks like a networking issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, with common usage of WiFi and multiple devices per location needing Internet access, most devices get their Internet access via a local network router. It is increasingly rare for a computer to be connected *directly* to an Internet modem anymore.

As such, using a router would prevent outside clients from being able to *directly* access your server's UDP port from over the Internet. In this case, the LAN router would need to have **port forwarding** configured on it (either manually by an admin, or in code via uPNP) to forward incoming UDP packets from the router's public WAN IP to the server's LAN IP.  Then outside clients can send packets to the router's WAN IP and have them reach your server's UDP port for `recvfrom()` to read.

Comment: To add to the answer, some Internet Service Providers don't allow their customers to do port-forwarding for some reason. Even if they do, enabling port-forwarding is extremely risky because it exposes your computer to potentially unauthorized remote access, and opens the door for malware/ransomware. Most local/personal computers don't have their firewall configured correctly, don't disable vulnerable ports, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense however do you know of anything I could use to send data from one device to another as my end goal is to create an online video game using C++ and UDP?

Comment: @JackKoscheka You need to rent a VPS for that, don't use your personal computer.

Comment: @thedemons Thanks I will look into that. Will I then be able to communicate to it using similar code to what I have above for my client simply modifying the IP address?

Comment: @thedemons ISPs can't prevent port forwarding, since that is a local setting. They can only block inbound traffic if it wasn't initiated from the customer side first. If the server were to send out first, that would open up the firewall. You would just have to make sure the packet goes out using the same LAN port that you want the router's port forwarding to send incoming packets to from the WAN.